# Mapping a MySQL docker port outside in an already running mysql container

Tags: docker

Let me describe my situation.

I have a mysql docker running as below in a Azure VM:

```
docker ps output:

67b7d4f1eca6  2c9028880e58  "docker-entrypoint.s…"  4dayago  Up7hours(healthy) 3306/tcp, 33060/tcp mysql                                                                     


docker image ls output:
something.azurecr.io/mysql  latest  2c9028880e58    3 months ago        447MB


uname -a
Linux pradipmazure1 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now as we can see the mysql is not exposed to any outside port such that I can see it from my workstation outside of the VM.

I can not redeploy the whole VM anymore as it's a part of prod.

I would like to do something such that the mysql can potentially be exposed outside in some port of the same Azure Linux VM.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the incoming traffic on port 3306 (or whatever port you want to expose MySql on) to port 3306 in the container. The container has an IP address on the bridge network that is reachable from the host. You can find the IP address of your container by running

```
docker inspect network bridge
```

When you've found the IP address, you can use `redir` to redirect the traffic with

```
redir --lport=3306 --caddr=172.17.0.2 --cport=3306
```

You need to run `redir` on the host. `lport` is the port you want to listen on. `caddr` is the IP address of the container.

For a cleaner solution you could even run `redir` in a new container. This might help you if you want to go that way: https://hub.docker.com/r/fr3nd/redir

Comment: One question. My host is a window 10 laptop from where I want to see the SQL db in a SQL workbench.Can I get redir in windows? I doubt. So in that case what may be the window equivalent of redir.

Comment: If your host is Windows, then the easiest way might be redir in a new container. Expose the port on the redir container and route the traffic into the mysql container.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Kilian.
Just for reference, so in my Azure VM, I need to have a docker-compose-redir.yml contains the expose 3306, command: redir --lport=3306 --cport=3306 --caddr=mysql_container_ip, port 3306. 
And in my windows host, I need to access the redir_container_ip:3306.
Is this correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have in mind, because you can't recreate the MySQL container, is to link containers which need MySQL by [the deprecated `--link` option](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/).